# Eliminate render-blocking resources ( lighthouse)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, lighthouse

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BookNotes</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta httpEquiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have this html page , I want to use Roboto font stylesheets , but in the way like I use it Lighthouse give me this warning :

[image]

What is the best way to optimize it ? I've read that I can use `defer` or `async` attribute, for loading it in async way of after rendering , but if I will load it after rendering , it will not apply styles for my font , etc . Will be really appreciate your help. If you need additional info , pls let me know .

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think the best way to deal with this is loading the fonts asynchronously. However, this might lead to font blinking, meaning that a font is first the default and then gets rerendered to the newly loaded font. To remedy this, you can hide the contents of the page until the font is loaded, and show it with a callback. You can take a look at [webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#readme). You also have to have fallback for the rare cases when someone has JS disabled.

JavaScript

```
var WebFont = require('webfontloader');

WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: ['Roboto']
  }
});
document.querySelector('html').classList.remove('no-js')
```

CSS

```
html {opacity: 0;}
html .wf-active, html.wf-inactive, html.no-js {opacity: 1;}
```

HTML

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found better solution:

```
 <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
      media="print"
      onload="this.media='all'"
    />
```

This is working well

Comment: This is kinda hacky, and it's not set in stone that it will work for all browsers or new versions of browsers. Use at your own risk.